# Azure PowerShell - get VM usage from across all subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I want to list all the VMs that generate costs in a specific timeframe or billing period.

I managed to create this script to get me the desired output:

```
$file="C:\temp\GeneratedCost-short.csv"

(az consumption usage list `
--start-date "2020-07-01" --end-date "2020-07-31" | ConvertFrom-Json)`
| Where-Object {$_.product -Match "Virtual Machines"}`
| Sort-Object -Property instanceName -Descending | Select-Object instanceName, subscriptionName`
| Get-Unique -AsString | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content $file
```

But this will give me the output only for the current subscription.

How can I run on all the subscriptions that I have on the azure tenant?

I tried using the below version but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$file="C:\temp\GeneratedCost-short.csv"

$VMs = @()
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | az account set -s $sub.Name
    $VMs += (az consumption usage list --start-date "2020-07-01" --end-date "2020-07-03" | ConvertFrom-Json)
}
# 
$VMs | Where-Object {$_.product -Match "Virtual Machines"}`
| Sort-Object -Property instanceName -Descending | Select-Object instanceName, subscriptionName`
| Get-Unique -AsString | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content $file
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing the Azure PowerShell module and Azure CLI could be causing issues with your code if the accounts haven't been retrieved between the two. Verify that az cli has the proper subscriptions

```
az account list -o table
```

If you don't see the accounts be sure to re-run `az login`.

Here's your code with the azure cli only

```
$file="C:\temp\GeneratedCost-short.csv"

$VMs = @()
az account list -o json | ConvertFrom-Json |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Getting usage for account: " $_.Name
az account set -s $_.Name
    $VMs += (az consumption usage list --start-date "2020-07-01" --end-date "2020-07-03" | ConvertFrom-Json)
    }

$VMs | Where-Object {$_.product -Match "Virtual Machines"} |
    Sort-Object -Property instanceName -Descending |
        Select-Object instanceName, subscriptionName |
            Get-Unique -AsString | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
                Set-Content $file
```

Comment: I encountered something strange, if I run the above version of the script I get the error:
```Getting usage for subscription:  Subscription1 Subscription2
UnrecognizedArgumentError: unrecognized arguments: Subscription2```
and it gets the VMs from only one subscription. If I run the script multiple times it changes random the subscription that will show the VMs.
If I run the below version to get the subscriptions the error is not present anymore and it shows for all subscriptions, I will write it in the next comment.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: ```$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
    az account set -s $sub.Name
    $VMs += (az consumption usage list --start-date "2020-07-01" --end-date "2020-07-03" | ConvertFrom-Json)
}```

Answer (score 0):

never do `+=` on an array, worst pattern ever.

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]$VMs = @()
$subs = Get-AzSubscription # | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Enabled'}
foreach ($s in $subs) {
  Set-AzContext -SubscriptionObject $s | Out-Null
  $vm = # your search here ...
  $VMs.Add($vm)
 }
```